# Google script creating automatic reponses to a form from emails into specific label on my inbox stop working after 6 months of running fine

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

We have a google form created by a group and they require that people fill in the form to request work from them.  We are releasing request through and email with specific format so I end up creating this script that parse the form owner's email, get the information for each email create a response, submit and record the email id in another sheet to avoid processing it again.

It was working fine and properly for the last 6 months creating the responses and recording the log, but suddenly it just stop working on the submit step.. 
when debugging it captures everything, it doesn't throw and error message or break the code it just try to "submit" but the response never gets to the form and then the code keeps running and recording the id on the log sheet as usual.

Does anybody have face this? where I should be looking to fix this situations..

here is my code so you can take a look.  By the way.. the user is running this script every hour.

```
var OTHER = "*Other";

function getAlias_(list_choices, target_choice) {
  var i;
  var alias = OTHER;
  var alias_lower = "";
  var target_lower = target_choice.toLowerCase();

  for (i=0;i<=list_choices.length-1;i++) {
    alias_lower = list_choices[i].getValue().replace("*","").toLowerCase();
    if (target_lower.search(alias_lower) >= 0) {
      alias = list_choices[i].getValue();
      break;
    }
  }

  return alias;
}

function getCustomerFileName_(body) {
  var res = "";
  var tag = "Customer Filename";
  var section = body.substring(body.length/2,body.length);
  var pos = section.search(tag);
  var pos2 = 0;
  if (pos >= 0) {
    pos2 = section.substring(pos,section.length).search("size=2>");
    res = section.substring(pos+pos2+7,section.length);
    pos2 = res.search("</font>");
    res = res.substring(0,pos2);
    if (res.toLowerCase().search("type of proof") >= 0) {
      res = "(Please Refer to LS2)";
    }
  }

  return res.trim();
}

function getPrepressInstructions_(body) {
  var res = "";
  var tag = "Prepress Instructions";
  var section = body.substring(1,body.length);
  var pos = section.search(tag);
  var pos2 = 0;
  if (pos >= 0) {
    pos2 = section.substring(pos,section.length).search("size=2>");
    res = section.substring(pos+pos2+7,section.length);
    pos2 = res.search("</font>");
    res = res.substring(0,pos2);
    if (res.toLowerCase().search("proof instructions") >= 0) {
      res = "";
    }
  }

  return res.trim();
}

function getEmailElement_(body, tag) {
  var res = "";
  var section = body.substring(0,body.length);
  var pos = section.search(tag);
  var pos2 = 0;
  if (pos >= 0) {
    pos2 = section.substring(pos,section.length).search("size=2>");
    res = section.substring(pos+pos2+7,section.length);
    pos2 = res.search("</font>");
    res = res.substring(0,pos2);
  }

  return res.trim();
}



function checkIfAlreadyEntered_(sheet, aCustomer, aPart, aVersion, aFile) {
  var res = false;
  var searchResult = -1;
  var part = "";
  var file = "";
  var customer = "";
  var version = "";
  var index = 0;

  var partValues = sheet.getRange("K:K").getValues();

  for (index=1;index < partValues.length; index++) {
    part = partValues[index][0];
    if (part == "") break;
    if (part == aPart) {
      file = sheet.getRange("L"+(index+1)).getValue();
      if (file == aFile) {
        customer = sheet.getRange("C"+(index+1)).getValue()
        if (customer == aCustomer) {
          version = sheet.getRange("BT"+(index+1)).getValue();
          if (version.search("[PART VERSION: "+aVersion+"]") >= 0) {
              res = true;
          }
        }
      }
    } 
    if (res) break;
  }
  partValues = null;

  return res;
}

function checkIfAlreadyEnteredById_(sheet, anId) {
  var res = false;
  var searchResult = -1;
  var id = "";
  var index = 0;

  var partValues = sheet.getRange("K:K").getValues();

  for (index=1;index < partValues.length; index++) {
    id = partValues[index][0];
    if (id == "") break;
    if (id == anId) {
      res= true;
    } 
    if (res) break;
  }
  partValues = null;

  return res;
}


function getDSGLocation_(instructions) {
  var res = "";
  if (instructions.search("menasha") >= 0) {
    res = "Menasha";
  } else {
    if (instructions.search("seattle") >= 0) {
      res = "Seattle";
    } else {
      if (instructions.search("chanhassen") >= 0) {
        res = "Chanhassen";
      } 
    }
  }
  return res;
}

function getElementFromInstructions_(instructions,tag) {
  var res = "";
  var segmento = "";
  var car = "";
  var i;
  var found = 0;

  if (tag == "") found = 1;

  for (i=0;i<instructions.length;i++) {
    car = instructions.substr(i,1);
    if ( car == "[") {
      i++;
      car = instructions.substr(i,1);
      while (car != "]" && i < instructions.length) {
        if (car == tag) found = 1;
        res = res + car;
        i++;
        car = instructions.substr(i,1);
      }
      if (found == 1) {
        break;
      } else {
        res = "";
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}

function CheckMailForDSGAndSubmitRequest() {

  var num_messages = 5;       // will be applied to the last n messages. Google allows up to 500

  // *************************************************
  // Defining Positions for each Question in Form
  // *************************************************
  var items_positions = {
    CustomerName:0, // ListItem
    CustomerOther:1, // TextItem
    RunInformation:2, // MultpleChoiceItem
    DSGLocation:3, // MultipleChoiceItem
    ChanhassenOrderType:5, // MultipleChoiceItem
    MenashaSeattleOrderType: 10, // MultipleChoiceItem
    PartNumber:12, //TextItem
    ArtFileName:13, // TextItem
    AdditionalInstructions:79, //ParagraphType
    AdditionalContacts:80 //TextItem
  };
  // *************************************************

  var filter_tag_subject = "File Notification - ";
  var filter_tag_to = <email been search on to:>;
  var default_contact = <default email>;
  var partNumber = "";
  var partVersion = "";
  var customerName = "";
  var customerAlias = "";
  var customerFileName = "";
  var DSGLocationName = "";
  var additionalContacts = "";
  var prepressInstructions = "";
  var alias = "";
  var txt = "";
  var answers = new Array;
  var action = "";
  var result = "";
  var i;
  var target_date = new Date(2017,9,4);
  //var target_date = new Date();
  var target_date_str = (target_date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+target_date.getDate()+"/"+target_date.getFullYear();
  var wait_time = 1 * 60000;    // 60000 is to convert to miliseconds the number of minutes entered to wait
  var wait_time_submit = 1 * 20000;

  var logEnvironment = "TEST";  // TEST for Testing environment, PRODUCTION for production

  // Get Ids for the Google Form and Response Spreadsheet
  if (logEnvironment == "TEST") {
    var premediaFormId = <test form id>;
    var responseWorkbookId = <test response sheet id>;
    var logWorkbookId = <test log sheet id>;
  } else {
    var premediaFormId = <production form id>;
    var responseWorkbookId = <production response sheet id>;
    var logWorkbookId = <production log sheet id>;
  }

  // Google Form

  var premediaForm = FormApp.openById(premediaFormId);
  var premediaFormItems = premediaForm.getItems();
  /*for (var i = 0; i < premediaFomrItems.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(premediaFormItems[i]);
  }
  return 0*/

  // Responses Spreadsheet linked to the Google Form

  var responseWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(responseWorkbookId);
  var responseSheet = responseWorkbook.getSheetByName("Form Responses 3")

  // PSG Spreadsheet to keep a log of entries on the Google Form above mentioned
  var logWorkbook  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logWorkbookId);
  var logSheet = logWorkbook.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  if (logSheet.getRange("A1").getValue() == "") {
    logSheet.appendRow(["Time Stamp","Author","Email Date", "Customer Name","Part Number","Version", "File Name", "Result", "Action","Environment","Id"]);
  }
    logSheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), Session.getActiveUser(), '**********', '**********', '**********','**********', '**********','**********', "Script Started", logEnvironment, '**********']);

  // Get the company field choices so we can make the proper conversion between the 
  // company shown on the email and the value to be entered on the form. 
  // this list will be used on getAlias_() function
  var form_companyChoices = premediaFormItems[0].asListItem().getChoices()

  // Define where the script will be retrieving the emails
  var labelName = "PSG_Premedia_Requests";
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var threads = label.getThreads(0,num_messages);
  Logger.clear();

  for ( i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var msg_to = msg.getTo();
    var msg_subject = msg.getSubject();
    var msg_datetime = msg.getDate();
    var msg_date = (msg_datetime.getMonth()+1)+"/"+msg_datetime.getDate()+"/"+msg_datetime.getFullYear();
    var msg_time = msg_datetime.getHours()+":"+msg_datetime.getMinutes();
    var msg_body = msg.getBody();
    var msg_id = msg.getId();

      if (msg_subject.search(filter_tag_subject) >= 0 && msg_to.search(filter_tag_to) >= 0) {
        if (new Date(msg_date) >= new Date(target_date_str)) {
          if (!checkIfAlreadyEnteredById_(logSheet,msg_id)) {
            answers = new Array;
            partNumber = msg_subject.substring(msg_subject.search(filter_tag_subject)+filter_tag_subject.length,msg_subject.length).replace("File Notification","").trim();
            customerName = msg_subject.substring(0,msg_subject.search(filter_tag_subject)).replace("New ","").trim();
            customerAlias = getAlias_(form_companyChoices,customerName);
            customerFileName = getCustomerFileName_(msg_body);
            partVersion = getEmailElement_(msg_body,"Version");
            prepressInstructions = getPrepressInstructions_(msg_body);

            var formResponse = premediaForm.createResponse();

            // Populating Answers
            answers[items_positions.CustomerName] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.CustomerName].asListItem().createResponse(customerAlias);
            if (customerAlias.search(OTHER.replace("*","")) >= 0) {
              answers[items_positions.CustomerOther] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.CustomerOther].asTextItem().createResponse(customerName);
            } else {
              answers[items_positions.CustomerOther] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.CustomerOther].asTextItem().createResponse("");
            }            
            answers[items_positions.RunInformation] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.RunInformation].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("New Job");

            DSGLocationName = getDSGLocation_(prepressInstructions.toLowerCase());
            if (DSGLocationName == ""){
              if (customerName.toLowerCase().search("samsung") >= 0) {
                DSGLocationName = "Chanhassen";
              } else {
                DSGLocationName = "Chanhassen";
              }
            }

            /*if (logEnvironment == "TEST") {
              additionalContacts = "jorge.a.reyes@rrd.com";
            } else {*/
              additionalContacts = getElementFromInstructions_(prepressInstructions,"@");
              if (additionalContacts == "") {
                additionalContacts = default_contact;
              }
           /* }
*/            

            answers[items_positions.DSGLocation] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.DSGLocation].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse(DSGLocationName);

            // This following lines were edited upon request by Daniel Cramm so both columns were updated regardless 

            if (DSGLocationName.toLowerCase() == "chanhassen") {
              var orderTypePos = items_positions.ChanhassenOrderType;
            } else {
              var orderTypePos = items_positions.MenashaSeattleOrderType;
            }
            answers[orderTypePos] = premediaFormItems[orderTypePos].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Package (PSG) w/ LS2"); 

            /*
            answers[items_positions.ChanhassenOrderType] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.ChanhassenOrderType].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Package (PSG) w/ LS2");
            answers[items_positions.MenashaSeattleOrderType] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.MenashaSeattleOrderType].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Package (PSG) w/ LS2");
            */
            answers[items_positions.PartNumber] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.PartNumber].asTextItem().createResponse(partNumber);
            answers[items_positions.ArtFileName] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.ArtFileName].asTextItem().createResponse(customerFileName);
            answers[items_positions.AdditionalInstructions] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.AdditionalInstructions].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(prepressInstructions+"\n\n[PART VERSION: "+partVersion+"]");
            answers[items_positions.AdditionalContacts] = premediaFormItems[items_positions.AdditionalContacts].asTextItem().createResponse(additionalContacts);

            // Applying answers to Form Response
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.CustomerName]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.CustomerOther]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.RunInformation]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.DSGLocation]);

            /*
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.ChanhassenOrderType]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.MenashaSeattleOrderType]);
            */

            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[orderTypePos]);


            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.PartNumber]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.ArtFileName]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.AdditionalInstructions]);
            formResponse.withItemResponse(answers[items_positions.AdditionalContacts]);

            var e = formResponse.submit();
            formResponse = null
            answers = null;
            action = "Form Entry on Reynosa_DSG_Submission_Form added successfully"

            result = "SUCCESS";
            logSheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), Session.getActiveUser(), msg_datetime, customerName, partNumber, partVersion, customerFileName, result, action, logEnvironment, msg_id]);
            Utilities.sleep(wait_time);

          } else {
            action = "Message with id " + msg_id + " already processed."
            result = "SKIPPED";
            //logSheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), Session.getActiveUser(), msg_datetime, '', '', '', '', result, action, logEnvironment, msg_id]);
          } 
         }
      }
  }

  logSheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), Session.getActiveUser(), '**********', '**********', '**********','**********', '**********','**********', "Script Completed", logEnvironment, '**********']);

  premediaForm = null;
  premediaFormItems = null;
  responseWorkbook = null;
  responseSheet = null;
  logWorkbook = null;
  logSheet = null;

};
```

Comment: Welcome. IMHO the question is too broad. If you didn't yet, please take a look to [Troubleshoogint](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) and into the [tag:debugging] wiki.

Comment: specifically.. the issue is when I issue the submit action. the script seems to be doing something but it is not saving the response on the form.  I don't know if there is a timing issue or a security issue since I'm not getting any error message.